# Scientific notation in knitr: How to improve typography

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

It has always been one of the great features of knitr that it does intelligent rounding, so you can avoid many `sprintf/round/paste0` detours.

After one customer complained that I had given decimals incorrectly, I noted that it is very dangerous to forget $$ for numbers that might be printed in scientific notation. But the same customer complained that my formatting using scientific notation looks ugly because the latex-like mathematics does not match the main font.

[image: scientific notation]

Following @yihui's comment on the closed issue (https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/864), the $$ are required.

Does someone have an intelligent solution for this? Currently, I am back to formatting everything with sprintf as in old days.

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: cosmo
---

I use the cosmo theme because it shows the typographic problem more clearly.

```{r}
options(digits=2)
mean = c(2.31310934, 1.23456e-7)
std = c(0.31310934, 6.54321e-7)
```

digits is `r getOption("digits")`

The mean is `r mean[1]` with a standard deviation of `r std[1]`.

This looks good

The mean is `r mean[2]` with a standard deviation of `r std[2]`.

Note that the aboves looks like "1.23510".

The mean is $`r mean[2]`$ with a standard deviation of $`r std[2]`$.
````

Comment: would you consider changing the font of the document to match the output of mathjax? That seems easier. I believe all you'd need is a couple of css lines to select STIX fonts.

Comment: Brr... back to UNIX sixties look? Not that I would love it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always redefine the `inline` output hook to avoid many explicit `sprintf/round/paste0`...

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  knitr:::format_sci(x, 'md')
})
```

This will use the syntax of the form `1.23 &times; 10^-7^` for scientific notations, which should work well if your output format is only HTML.

It is a simple problem for a specific type of output format, but it is hard when you want the number formatting to be portable across all formats, including HTML, Word, LaTeX, and so on. That is why `$ $` became required in knitr 1.7.

Comment: Thanks, Yihui, that should be a solution. You should probably not hide it under "minor points" in the documentation, I am sure in the next week more people will be bitten by the change. Would it be possible to make the above hook the default in HTML, and issue a warning when $$ is not used in other formats?

Comment: @DieterMenne To some degree, I agree it is not a minor change. I cannot make the above hook the default in HTML, however, because that will fail for people who do have `$ $` around their numbers. With portability in mind, the only solution is to require `$ $`, unfortunately...